# A Pigeonhole Problem

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

How do I find out how many students must be in a classroom in order for at least 3 of them to have a birthday in one of January, February, March, April or at least 4 of their birthdays in one of the remaining months?

For example, if there are 3 students all with a birthday in January this fulfills the condition, however if there are 3 students, 1 with a birthday in January, 1 in February, 1 in March, this will *not* fulfill the condition.

Comment: "at least 4 of their birthdays in one of the remaining months" is a bit ambiguous. Does this mean 4 birthdays across any of the remaining months or does it mean 4 birthdays in one determined month?

Comment: @ThomasBladt: I have edited my question.

Comment: You didn't clarify the confusion in your question. You just removed your work.

Comment: @Riley: That's because my work was wrong. 3 birthdays needed to be in one of the first 4 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the minimum number of students in the class that **guarantees** that either $3$ of them are born in the first $4$ months or $4$ of them are born in the last $8$ months.

Suppose there were only $12$ students in that classroom. Then there is no guarantee that the given criteria are fulfilled. It could happen that those $12$ students are born in $12$ different months. If there were $24$ students in the classroom, then again there is no guarantee of fulfilling the requirement; it could happen that exactly two of them were born in each month. Suppose there were $24+8=32$ students. Then it could happen that among them, $24$ of them are born in $12$ months with $2$ in each and the remaining $8$ are born in the months May to December, one in each. This again is not what we want. Now suppose there were $33$ students. Then the one extra student must be born either in the months Jan to April which fulfills the first criteria or born in May to December which fulfills the second criteria. So $33$ students in the class guarantees that the conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: I have rephrased the question and added clarification. Can you please look over it again?

Comment: The answer is still $33$.

Comment: Can you rephrase your answer then? I am having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Now i got it! Thanks!